# Awesome WM : How can I write a rule to make a window appear floating under the mouse?

Tags: awesome-wm, lua

I am using a clipboard manager and I would like to see it appear just under the mouse when I press a shortcut key.

I have written different rules for awesome wm, I see how to focus the good client, how to make it floating, how to make it appear at a fixed position..

I found this entry in the [Awesome FAQ](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_make_windows_spawn_under_the_mouse_cursor.3F).

However, I don't see how to use this tip to create a rule.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For global use by keyword**

at the end of your rc.lua you have the function `client.add_signal(...` , inside this function you have to set the last line of the FAQ, to enable it for only particular applications I included a new variable at the beginning of rc.lua `

```
local undermouse = false
```

than the part of the FAQ:

```
client.add_signal("manage", function (c, startup)
    -- Add a titlebar
    -- awful.titlebar.add(c, { modkey = modkey })

    -- Enable sloppy focus
    c:add_signal("mouse::enter", function(c)
        if awful.layout.get(c.screen) ~= awful.layout.suit.magnifier
        and awful.client.focus.filter(c) then
            client.focus = c
        end
    end)

    if not startup then
        -- Set the windows at the slave,
        -- i.e. put it at the end of others instead of setting it master.
        -- awful.client.setslave(c)

        -- Put windows in a smart way, only if they does not set an initial position.
        if not c.size_hints.user_position and not c.size_hints.program_position then
            awful.placement.no_overlap(c)
            awful.placement.no_offscreen(c)
=>          if underMouse == true then
=>              awful.placement.under_mouse(c)
=>              underMouse = false
=>          end
        end
    end
end)
```

to use this option I created the next code for my calculater key:

```
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(
    awful.key({                   }, "#148", function () 
        underMouse = true 
        awful.util.spawn(calculator) 
    end),
)
```

**As a rule for 1 application**

as found by yourself after testing my solution, but added to this answer for use for other people:

```
{ rule = { class = "Gnome-calculator",  },
    properties = { 
        floating = true,
        callback = function(c) awful.placement.under_mouse(c) end,
    },
},
```

Comment: @mperrin the down vote (not by me) is probably because I gave the solution and you give the solved at yourself for an answer that should be a comment to my answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, pretty new here. Your answer helped me a lot, but I thought that it didn't answer clearly to the question which was "how to write a rule...", that's why I didn't mark your answer as the accepted solution, but give it a up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your answer, and the highlight of the `awful.placement.under_mouse(c)` function.

Finally, writing the rule was really easy :

```
 { rule = { class = "Gnome-calculator",  },
    properties = { 
        floating = true,
        callback = function(c) awful.placement.under_mouse(c) end,
    },
},
```

Comment: Don't understand why this has been down voted.